# Need to set <p> according to select option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, validation

I need to update a para `<p>` tag when i change select option change but those select field in a same id 
this is my jsp code

```
<c:forEach var="roomOccupanice" items="${RoomOccRequestNow}">   
    <label value ="${roomOccupanice}"  class="roomOccupanice" id="roomOccupanice">${roomOccupanice}</label>
            <div class="custom-select-container">
               <select id="roomType" name="roomType" class="roomType">
                    <option value="N/A" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                    <c:forEach var="roomType" items="${RoomTypeRequestNow}">
                        <option value="${roomType}">${roomType}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>   
                <label class="select-arrow"></label>
            </div>
            <!-- End -->
            <div class="custom-select-container">
               <select id="roomCount" name="roomCount" class="roomCount">
                    <option value="N/A" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
                    <c:forEach var="roomCount" items="${RoomCountRequestNow}">
                        <option value="${roomCount}">${roomCount}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>   
                <label class="select-arrow"></label>
            </div>
</c:forEach>
```

i need to update this `<p>` when roomCount change

```
<p class="booking-desc custom-padding">${selectedStays}</p>
```

[image]

when i select room count, `<P>` should update like this roomCount.value roomOccupanicelable.value Eg: 1 Double Room(s);
multiple values also can select eg: 1 Single Room(s) 
 2 Double Room(s)

Comment: So, what have you tried? Can we see your script? Maybe a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Veritas87 i just tried to implement a logic when change   $('#roomCount').change(function(){ alert("Test")} but it's only affect 1st one

Comment: For multiple elements, select by tagname, classname, or something other than id.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with `$("select#roomCount").change(function(){}` function